# add packages to subiquity based installation

Tags: package-management, subiquity

I build a installation for servers and desktops by adding ubuntu-minimal-desktop
It works so far, but only when connected to wired-network

So I would like to add the wpasupplicant and the ubuntu-minimal-desktop and some other packages to the iso, so no network is needed at all
Is there an elegant way to add ?

Comment: Are you asking how to add packages to the .iso? Or are you asking how to tell cloud-init to install the packages? Or are you asking both? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: "Is there an elegant way to add ?"  You are asking a yes/no question and the answer is also subjective so this is likely to get closed. My answer: ypu do it the same way as you did ubuntu-minimal-desktop.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear here. The question is to add the packages to the iso. As an unelegant way I would see something like downloading by hand, put it in a folder and install with "dpkg -i *" Most elegant would be something like having  script to download packages with dependencies, make them a repo and add then with the packages statement.

Answer (score 3):

I've also been working at this but for ubuntu live server 20.04. I don't know if it applies for Ubuntu Desktop.

The idea is to rebuild the iso after modifying casper/filesystem.squashfs and setting up subiquity/autoinstall.
But sometimes, pre-installing some packages seems to break the installer (like ifenslave package) so I install those packages in the late stages of auto-install.

So to pre-install some packages on the iso you have two possibilites :

#### Modify capser/filesystem.squashfs

The general idea is to :

1. mount the original live iso
2. mount casper/filesystem.squashfs
3. chroot and install your packages
4. repack the new casper/filesystem.squashfs
5. update some other files on the iso
6. rebuild the iso

Some references I've used :

[1] https://medium.com/100-days-of-linux/chroot-a-linux-wonder-fc36ed08087e : Putting up subiquity/autoinstall for automated install, nocloud style

[2] https://github.com/ljfranklin/ubuntu-img-builder/blob/master/build.sh : Script demonstrating capser/filesystem.squashfs modification

[3] https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/main/scripts/inject-subiquity-snap.sh#L194 : great script from canonical subiquity demonstrating how practical overlayfs is and a simplified xorriso usage

#### Install packages in late stages of autoinstall

The idea here is to use apt to download the packages and the missing dependencies and install them later during autoinstall late-command stage.
It would imply the following steps :

1. mount the original live iso.
2. mount casper/filesystem.squashfs.
3. chroot and use `apt-get install --download-only -y -o Dir::Cache="/yourcache" -o Dir::Cache::archives="archives/" ${listOfPackages}`. This will download the targeted packages and their dependencies missing from filesystem.squashfs.
4. Setup subiquity autoinstall to install those packages at the end of autoinstall procedure like below : I tried to use apt install by specifying the cache dir but doesn't work with curtin. So instead I use  `dpkg --unpack *.deb; apt-get install --no-download -yf`. It's not as clean as using apt but for me it did the job

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
version: 1
interactive-sections:
# ...
late-commands:
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash -c 'cd /yourcache/archives; dpkg --unpack *.deb; apt-get install --no-download -yf'
    # - curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash -c 'apt-get install --print-uris --no-download -y -f -o Dir::Cache="/awrepo" -o Dir::Cache::archives="archives/" __PARAM_PACKAGES_POST__' # doesn't work. use dpkg --unpack instead
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get --purge -y --quiet=2 autoremove
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get clean
```

Here is the gist of all this put together : https://gist.github.com/creatldd1/eec887f3f8a0bf48e0e9dec1598b8614

NB : An alternative to local apt cache would be to build a local apt repo on the iso and configure apt to use it. The problem is that the size of the repo can be huge.
It was my first approach but I gave it up.

Great link to configure a simple repo : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595448/402499.

The code to download the package and its dependencies, recursively :

```bsh
listPkg=$(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks ${theListofPackages} | grep "^\w" | sort --unique )
for pkg in ${listPkg}
do
    if ! apt-get download ${pkg}; then
        echo >&2 " WARNING : problem fetching package ${pkg}. Keeping on"
    fi
done
```

More info on that, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008193/how-to-list-download-the-recursive-dependencies-of-a-debian-package